# Возвращать по запросу картинку, которая скрыта

Tags: php

На сервере есть папка с картинками, доступа туда нет, она вне директории сайта.

Нужен скрипт, который по url site.com/pic будет возвращать разные картинки в зависимости от текущего пользователя (соответствие какому пользователю какую картинку показывать есть в БД).

Как нужно правильно прочитать файл на сервере и отдать прочитанные данные в виде картинки?

Картинка, показанная пользователю не должна быть опубликована публично, т.е. не должно быть какого-то url, где можно получить эту картинку без авторизации пользователя

Comment: Так а в чем проблема-то? (здесь форум вопросов и ответов, не фриланс биржа)

Comment: Форматы изображений заранее известны? Можно ориентироваться только на jpg, gif и png?

Comment: @cheops Да, известны, jpg,gif и png

Answer (score 0):

В pic.php или pic/index.php надо поместить что-то типа:

```
if ($authorized_user==true) // условие авторизации
{
 header("Content-type: image/jpeg"); // указание на тип отдаваемого контента, конечно, вам надо будет здесь сделать условие в зависимости от типа картинки, которую будете передавать
 echo $cureent_user_image; // в эту переменную надо будет заранее передать изображение для конкретного пользователя, но на самом деле, конечно, лучше сделать это через специальную функцию, которая будет возвращать значение картинки, в зависимости от конкретной авторизации
}
else echo "404"; // если пользователь неавторизован
```

Также я бы советовал, если используется Apache - включить модуль `mod_rewrite`, это позволило бы не создавать отдельный pic.php в качестве обработчика, а обрабатывать запрос из основного скрипта.

Если вы используете ngnix - пользователь Ипатьев рекомендует обратить внимание на заголовок `X-Accel-Redirect` для реализации контролируемых
скачиваний: http://www.opennet.ru/base/net/nginx_x_accel_redirect.txt.html

Comment: mod_rewrite тут не принципиален, прямо скажем. А вот отдавать картинки надо с умом, а не просто эхо, пока клиент не заберет.

Comment: @Ипатьев Да, не принципиален. Обработчиком может быть `pic.php`

Comment: ну вот и надо факультативные меры упоминать мельком, а не писать так, будто это принципиально необходимый элемент

Comment: @Ипатьев Исправил. Так корректнее?

Comment: Нет. Зачем в ответе про отдачу картинки читать про организацию ЧПУ - загадка.

Comment: Комментарий про post/get - ад. Звучит так, как будто предложенное решение использует какой-то другой тип запроса.

Comment: @Ипатьев Но ведь иначе придётся делать отдельный скрипт. А с `mod-rewrite` можно поместить обработчик отдачи картинки в основной скрипт. Сейчас тогда исправлю ответ, чтобы эта мысль была озвучена.

Comment: Запихать весь код сайта в один index.php - это очень, очень мудрая идея. На грани гениальности.

Comment: @Ипатьев Считаете, что вообще про `mod_rewrite` не стоит упоминать в этом ответе?

Comment: Да, считаю что это только сбивает с толку и отвлекает внимание от основного принципа. А вот про X-Accel-Redirect в Nginx упомянуть стоит.

Comment: @Ипатьев Ещё `X-SendFile` упомянуть не повредит, апач популярен всё-таки.